# How to tell what entities the default GCP Cloud Vision API supports?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to find out what entities are supported by the default Google Cloud Platform Cloud Vision API, specifically for Object Localization and Label Detection features. It appears that the default model for GCP Cloud Vision API has significantly changed in the last few months. Specifically, the current API results lack localized objects (label name and bounding box, e.g. "cat" and coordinates for the image region containing the cat) that were available previously, say around June 2021.

(1) Is there any official list of labels that are supported by the GCP Cloud Vision API? For example, does that team communicate what labels the model supports?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please confirm what [Vision API feature](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/features-list) are you using? This will help me to do an investigation if there is an entity list. Likewise, please provide any additional details as you can about your inquiry to be able to better assist you.

Comment: @Orlandog yes, the GCP Vision API Object Localization and Label Detection features. I updated the answer to specifically call out those two features with more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid to say that there isn't a known list of what object categories are able to recognize Vision API.

According to the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes), there has been no change in the object localization and label detection feature model after June 2021 so it is rare that you had have a change in the expected quality of recognition for these features.

Likewise, please consider that this detection is based on Machine Learning models; that although they're constantly improving, they might not be able to accurately detect all the objects. Additionally to this, please keep in mind that a good recognition also depends on the quality of the input data; in which case, I suggest you validate the [recommended size of the input images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files#image_sizing) to get an optimal recognition.

Finally, if you need recognition of specialized objects I recommend you consider [AutoML object detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs) to develop a customized recognition model.